# Regex for get phrases enclosed in Double Quotes

Tags: java, regex, text

I need help to build a regular expression. I'm programming a software that looks for certain words in a string. But I need to also look for **phrases**. This string is entered by the user in a text box.

Currently I use the following regular expression `\s+` to replace spaces by ampersands: 
`word1 word2 word3` to `word1&word2&word3`

My new requirement must include phrases enclosed in quotes, like the searching for phrases in Google.

```
"word1 word2" "word3 word4" word5
```

Must be:

```
word1 word2&word3 word4&word5
```

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**: If there is another way or another approach to do the same, I'm open to any idea.

Comment: You don't have a regular language anymore.

Comment: You cannot do it with regexp: regular expressions do not support any kind of counting. You need counting here, because the action is different when you see an odd number of quotes vs. an even number of quotes. If there is a reasonably low limit on the number of quoted items in a single line, you could fake it by doing the counting yourself, but the expression is not going to be pretty; otherwise, you should build something more robust.

Comment: Well i don't have a solution of your problem but here is a very good site where u can write and check whether your regular expression is correct or not.Hope it will help you. http://zytrax.com/tech/web/regex.htm

Comment: @PaulP.R.O. - Why isn't it regular?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight - Wrong. Regular expressions support counting with a *constant boundary*. Here, you never have to count more than **2**. I agree a simple parser *might* be an option here, if you want to support more features in the future, but there is nothing here a simple academic regular expression cannot do.

Comment: @Kobi Bounded limit is precisely what I implied when I said that there is a hack that works for low number of quoted items. If you would like to do the whole string at once, you do need to count to more than two, but if you know that, for example, the line will never have more than ten components, you can create ugly expressions to differentiate an unescaped quote preceded by an odd number of unescaped quotes from an unescaped quote preceded by an even number of unescaped quotes, up to a fixed upper limit. This is what I ment by "doing the counting yourself".

Comment: @dasblinkenlight - I'm not sure I understand. Why would you count *anything* here? What is "**do** the whole string at once"? Who mentioned escaped quotes? Besides, while I fully agree regular expressions cannot count, they can easily tell even from odd. (let me know when I'm being difficult, by the way). Also: http://rubular.com/r/i0RvzqHVRS

Comment: @Kobi By "doing the whole string at once" I meant building a regexp that can differentiate between a space inside quotes and a space outside of quotes. This is in contrast to finding quoted word sequences, such as in your solution, where odd/even counting occurs naturally by virtue of consuming quotes in pairs. I mentioned escaped quotes to mention that it is possible to build a solution to even a more complex problem - it is not required to solve the OP's problem.

Comment: @Paulpro What are you talking about?

Comment: @PaulVargas Not really sure what I was talking about. I guess I thought that were nested strings your example rather than two strings side by side.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This assumes the quests are well balanced - you have an even number of quests, and not quests in middle of words.

You can match for `/"([^"]+)"|(\S+)/` - this will result in your words - quoted strings or non-spaces. It captured the word in group 1 *or* 2, and you can then `join` the results with the `&` delimiter.

Another option: you can get it in a single replace, by which is very similar way to the first pattern, by skipping over your tokens. Here's a JavaScript example:

```
s = s.replace(/(?:"([^"]+)"|(\S+))\s*/g, '$1$2&');
```

(note that you will have an extra ampersand in the end of the string)

Comment: I tried `"([^"]+)"|(\S+)` in Java and I have seen that this find the strings. With this regular expression I can find every word or phrase. Not for replace but yes to find.

Comment: @Paul - That is correct, I said you will have to `join` then to a new string, which isn't that bad, is it? `:)`